# Click position registered before focus lost but event run after focus lost

Tags: javascript, css

I have a textarea with a css rule that changes it's height when focused. Unfortunately, the click event registers it's position before the textarea loses focus, but the event gets carried out after the textarea has lost focus and the button therefore isn't at the same position.

This behaviour seems to be cross-browser consistant, I've tried it in FF, Chrome and Opera. Should this be considered a bug, and how can i circumvent this problem?

html:

```
<form>  
    <textarea></textarea><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="alert('clicked!'); return false;">
</form>
```

css:

```
TEXTAREA:focus {
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: looks like it's time to sign up for jsfiddle

Comment: Seems exactly right to me.

Comment: So basically your button is running away from the click?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Yes, exactly! Do you have any workarounds in hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real solution I can think of is to add a slight delay to resizing.  Something like this (jquery):

```
$("textarea").focus(function(){
      $(this).css("height", "200px");  
}).blur(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.css("height", "50px"); 
    },100);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FcCca/

Alternatively, a CSS transition solution:

```
textarea {
    transition-property: height;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    transition-timing-function: step-end;
    height: 20px;
}

textarea:focus{
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FcCca/2/

Comment: my thoughts exactly :)

Comment: Well, it sure does the trick! It just seemed a bit odd to me that the click event occurs after the blur event...

Comment: @KarlisRode  Answer updated with a css transition approach as well if you would prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a css transition and set a delay.  or you can do javascript and set a timeout.

it's doing what it's supposed to do, it looses focus, the box sizes down, then it handles the click.  Why not make the onfocus event add permanently a height:120 class,  and if you optionally want, have a "Less" button to make the box smaller again.